# Do I have to use Zend in order to get PHP version 7.0.0?

Tags: php, php-7

I just went over to *php.net* and saw that they have just released **PHP version 7.0.0**. Do I have to get `Zend` in order to use it or can I just update?

Comment: Put on hold because the question in it's current form makes no sense. Zend is a company. Do you have to get Zend? Zend What? Zend Engine, Zend Server, Zend Framework? Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about Zend, as the Zend Engine is part of the "package". For more info you can check their page [here](https://www.zend.com/en/community/php) or *php.net* itself.

Keep in mind that **PHP7 is in BETA phase**. Don't try to use it on something serious just yet.